# What's the syntax to run a cron job on heroku every hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, heroku, jobs

I just acquired the paid version of Heroku's cron, in order to run some tasks every hour. What I would like to know is the syntax I should use to actually get it to run every hour. So far I have this, Could you please tell me if it's correct:

```
desc "Tasks called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
  if Time.now.hour % 1 == 0 # run every sixty minutes?

    puts "Updating view counts...."
    Video.update_view_counts  
    puts "Finished....."

    puts "Updating video scores...."
    VideoPost.update_score_caches
    puts "Finished....."

    puts "Erasing videos....."
    Video.erase_videos!
    puts "Finished....."

  end

  if Time.now.hour == 0 # run at midnight

  end
end
```

I need to know if this line with the **1** in it is the way to go...

```
if Time.now.hour % 1 == 0
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run every hour, don't bother checking. Heroku will run it hourly.

Since %1 will always return 0, better to just have:

```
desc "Tasks called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
  puts "Updating view counts...."
  Video.update_view_counts  
  puts "Finished....."
  #...

  if Time.now.hour == 1 #1am
    #...
  end

end
```

Also, if you want to be able to run Video.update_view_counts when you need to, you could instead (after creating the rake task):

```
Rake::Task["video:update_view_counts"].invoke
```

That way you can run it inside of cron, and manually if needed

Answer (score 1):

Since, you already have an hourly cron, you don't have to check for the time to run the code.

```
task :cron => :environment do

    #<--- hourly cron begins 
    puts "Updating view counts...."
    Video.update_view_counts  
    puts "Finished....."

    puts "Updating video scores...."
    VideoPost.update_score_caches
    puts "Finished....."

    puts "Erasing videos....."
    Video.erase_videos!
    puts "Finished....."
    #hourly cron ends  --->

    if Time.now.hour == 0 # run at midnight

    end  

end
```